# what is the difference between UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait and UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I have looked at documentation but cannot find why sometimes the word mask is inserted and sometimes not.

Answer (score 5):

`UIInterfaceOrientationMask` is used by iOS 6's

```
-[UIViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations]
```

method ([docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations)), which is a bitmask of all the orientations your view controller will take, called by the sdk. The following is an example implementation:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape; // supports both landscape modes
}
```

This is in contrast to the pre iOS 6 (now deprecated, [docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation%3a)) method:

```
-[UIViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:]
```

which gave you a `UIInterfaceOrientation` enum value, to which you tested against with something like:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
   return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Note that you still get the `UIInterfaceOrientation` enum in the didRotate method as well as the `interfaceOrientaiton` property, which can be useful at other times.  The mask is only used when the sdk is deciding whether to rotate your view controller or not.

**Question for others:** has anyone noticed there is no `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitAll` mask?  Seems missing to me.

Comment: Using the bitwise OR operator ought to cover the 'PortraitAll' use case: return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown)

Comment: Yes that works, be there is a UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape, so I would hope there would be an equal version for portrait (has to of course be named something else.. which is why I appended *All).. just seems like an incomplete API to me.

Comment: @rich.e UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitAll is not required since     UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait = (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) and accoding to position of UIDeviceOrientationPortrait in the enum it corresponds to index number 0.