# UIImagePickerController not opening in iOS 6.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to open a `UIImagePickerController` object in my application using this code:

```
   self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
   self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
   self.imgPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
   [self presentViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But then the application crashes and displays the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 
'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!'
```

I also added following methods in my `ViewController` class

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

So, what else should I do to present this `UIImagePickerController`?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690963/preferredinterfaceorientationforpresentation-must-return-a-supported-interface-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be because the choose-photo VC doesn't implement the new orientation methods. To fix this, make sure for **root** view controller does implement them, even when the top VC doesn't.

In code:

```
@implementation UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    UIInterfaceOrientationMask topControllerOrientationMask = [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    return topControllerOrientationMask ? topControllerOrientationMask : UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    UIInterfaceOrientation topControllerOrientation = [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
    return topControllerOrientation ? topControllerOrientation : UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

About the crash problem you can read [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690963/preferredinterfaceorientationforpresentation-must-return-a-supported-interface-o)

Also `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` must return not `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`, but `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`,
 about the difference you can read [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136673/what-is-the-difference-between-uiinterfaceorientationmaskportrait-and-uiinterfac)

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your trying to launch image picker your app on iPad. If it is so, you cannot launch picker this type on iPad, it works only on iPhone. For using ImagePicker on iPad, launch imagePicker using UIPopOver.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem few days ago. I found this following trick.

Put this code in your

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

And also put this code in your `UIImagePickerViewController` class.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Because in `iOS-6` `UIImagePickerController` must be follow portrait orientation.

Comment: Add above method in AppDelegate.m , but not success. error continue.

Comment: @ChandreshKanetiya- you have UINavigationController ?

Comment: -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}